# Hiding the Active Movie Clip in a camera track?

Tags: animation, camera, transparency, video, tracking

Does anyone know how to hide an active movie clip but still keep the motion of the clip for the camera? Or is there a way to copy and paster the cameras path? Or create key frames for the camera path?

I am trying to do a motion track and get the camera to follow a certain motion path along with the clip so when I drop in particles they react with the camera but i do not want to see the active movie clip. I'm trying to just render the particles. I do not have much not knowledge in motion tracking and so trying to get the two things separated is getting a little frustrating. I pretty much want just particles in alpha space but reacting in the same way as if the clip is still there.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. Include images that can help us understand what you have set up so far. Show alos the compositing nodes.

Comment: You need to composite the clip or show it as a texture on a scene object to see it in the final render.